# Unable to resolve service for type 'Business.Abstract.IAuthService' while attempting to activate 'WebAPI.Controllers.AuthController'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac, .net-8.0

First of all I'm try to use n-layer architecture in my dotnet project.
Here is my error message: Unable to resolve service for type 'Business.Abstract.IAuthService' while attempting to activate 'WebAPI.Controllers.AuthController'

So basically I have a file which is called CoreModule in my Core project and I already create some extension for it and it's registering my core dependencies.
Afterwards I'm using Autofac in my Business layer. Here is the place that I'm registering my IAuthService for AuthManager.
Then in my Program.cs I'm using Populate method of Autofac to merge my own dependencies and my other dependencies which is created by Autofac.
I really do not where I'm making mistakes. I'm glad if you help me about it.

**Here is my Program.cs**

```
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Autofac;
using Core.DependencyResolvers;
using Core.Extensions;
using Core.Utilities.IoC;
using Core.Utilities.Security.Encryption;
using Core.Utilities.Security.JWT;
using DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Business.DependencyResolvers.Autofac;
using Business.Abstract;
using Business.Concrete;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddCors();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var tokenOptions = builder.Configuration.GetSection("TokenOptions").Get<TokenOptions>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidIssuer = tokenOptions.Issuer,
            ValidAudience = tokenOptions.Audience,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = SecurityKeyHelper.CreateSecurityKey(tokenOptions.SecurityKey)
        };
    });

var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

serviceCollection.AddDependencyResolvers(new ICoreModule[]
{
    new CoreModule()
});

serviceCollection.AddDbContext<NorthwindContext>();

//TODO: refactor
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

containerBuilder.Populate(serviceCollection);

containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new AutofacBusinessModule());

var container = containerBuilder.Build();
var serviceProvider = new AutofacServiceProvider(container);


var app = builder.Build();


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.ConfigureCustomExceptionMiddleware();

app.UseCors(builder=>builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyHeader());

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**Here is my AuthController**

```
using Business.Abstract;
using Entities.DTOs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Business.ValidationRules.FluentValidation;
using Core.Aspects.Autofac.Validation;
using Core.Entities.Concrete;
using Core.Utilities.Results;
using IResult = Core.Utilities.Results.IResult;

namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AuthController : Controller
    {
        private IAuthService _authService;

        public AuthController(IAuthService authService)
        {
            _authService = authService;
        }

        [HttpPost("login")]
        [ValidationAspect(typeof(UserValidator))]
        public IResult Login(UserForLoginDto userForLoginDto)
        {
            var userToLogin = _authService.Login(userForLoginDto);
            if (!userToLogin.Success)
            {
                return new ErrorResult(userToLogin.Message);
            }

            var result = _authService.CreateAccessToken(userToLogin.Data);
            if (result.Success)
            {
                userToLogin.Data.Token = result.Data;
                return new SuccessDataResult<User>(userToLogin.Data);
            }

            return new ErrorResult(result.Message);
            
        }

        [HttpPost("register")]
        public IResult Register(UserForRegisterDto userForRegisterDto)
        {
            var userExists = _authService.UserExists(userForRegisterDto.Email);
            if (!userExists.Success)
            {
                return new ErrorResult(userExists.Message);
            }

            var registerResult = _authService.Register(userForRegisterDto, userForRegisterDto.Password);
            var result = _authService.CreateAccessToken(registerResult.Data);
            if (result.Success)
            {
                registerResult.Data.Token = result.Data;
                return new SuccessDataResult<User>(registerResult.Data);
            }

            return new ErrorResult(result.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my AutofacBusinessModule**

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy;
using Business.Abstract;
using Business.Concrete;
using Castle.DynamicProxy;
using Core.Utilities.Interceptors;
using Core.Utilities.Security.JWT;
using DataAccess.Abstract;
using DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFramework;

namespace Business.DependencyResolvers.Autofac
{
    public class AutofacBusinessModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {

            builder.RegisterType<ProductManager>().As<IProductService>().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<EfProductDal>().As<IProductDal>().SingleInstance();

            builder.RegisterType<CategoryManager>().As<ICategoryService>().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<EfCategoryDal>().As<ICategoryDal>().SingleInstance();

            builder.RegisterType<UserManager>().As<IUserService>();
            builder.RegisterType<EfUserDal>().As<IUserDal>();

            builder.RegisterType<AuthManager>().As<IAuthService>().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<JwtHelper>().As<ITokenHelper>().SingleInstance();

            var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .EnableInterfaceInterceptors(new ProxyGenerationOptions()
                {
                    Selector = new AspectInterceptorSelector()
                }).SingleInstance();
            
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my CoreModule**

```
using Core.CrossCuttingConcerns.Caching;
using Core.CrossCuttingConcerns.Caching.Microsoft;
using Core.Utilities.IoC;
using Core.Utilities.Security.JWT;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Core.DependencyResolvers
{
    public class CoreModule : ICoreModule
    {
        public void Load(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddMemoryCache();
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ICacheManager, MemoryCacheManager>();
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my ServiceCollectionExtension**

```
using Core.Utilities.IoC;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Core.Extensions
{
    public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddDependencyResolvers
            (this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, ICoreModule[] modules)
        {
            foreach (var module in modules)
            {
                module.Load(serviceCollection);
            }

            return ServiceTool.Create(serviceCollection);
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the all stackTrace of error**

```
crit: Core.Extensions.ExceptionMiddleware[0]
      Unable to resolve service for type 'Business.Abstract.IAuthService' while attempting to activate 'WebAPI.Controllers.AuthController'.
crit: Core.Extensions.ExceptionMiddleware[0]
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ThrowHelperUnableToResolveService(Type type, Type requiredBy)
         at lambda_method14(Closure, IServiceProvider, Object[])
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Core.Extensions.ExceptionMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, ILogger`1 logger) in D:\WorkFiles\ProjectWiseSoftAspNet\Core\Extensions\ExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 26
```

I tried to also add AddScoped and it didn't work, I checked out Autofac documentation to see what I'm doing but also it says same things that I have done in my program.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know to use 3rd-party DI container you need to substitute the default one. Something along these lines (not tested, requires `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection` nuget):

```
builder.Host
   .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
   .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder =>
    {
        builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacBusinessModule());
    });
```

Instead of your handling of the `ContainerBuilder`.

See:

- [Autofac: ASP.NET Core integration](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#asp-net-core-3-0-and-generic-hosting)
- [ASP.NET Core 5 to ASP.NET Core 6 code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-8.0#aspnet-core-5-7)